# How to fix a commit accidentally marked as merge on SourceTree?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

SourceTree/Bitbucket/Git question: I was trying to merge master branch into feature branch in SourceTree, but a conflict was detected. SourceTree downloaded and staged all the changes from master branch and left me a conflicted file to fix. However, when I was resolving the conflict, I realized that I need to make some more changes to this file - so, I just unstaged all the files from the master branch and discarded all the changes in them, made a modification in that one remaining file and staged just that few lines and made the commit. But, SourceTree still classified it as a merge commit, it's marked as such on Bitbucket, despite the fact that this commit merely changed a few lines in that one file and none of the changes from the master branch were included.

The real problem is that when I'm trying to merge master into feature now, SourceTree says that the branch is 'Already up-to-date', despite the fact that it clearly is not, and I even can see it on Diff tab on Bitbucket. Apparently, Bitbucket thinks that everything was successfully merged with that previous commit, although it wasn't. How can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you mix something when resolving the conflict. Do you want to merge master branch into feature branch? If Yes, you should select feature branch as current branch, and click merge -> pick commit on master branch.

When the merge conflict appears, the current branch is still feature, it will show errors if you switch to master branch before resolving conflict.

If you want to make more changes before resolving the conflict, you should unstage all -> discard file -> switch to master branch -> make more changes -> commit.

After update the master branch -> switch feature as current branch -> merge -> pick commit on master branch -> resolve conflict.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge master branch into feature branch, only need to these:

```
git checkout feature 

git merge master
```

If you found some comflicts during merge.

1. The merge is not what you want during solving the merge conflicts, just type git `merge –abort` to stop it.
2. If you want to finish this merge, just fix conflicted file, after that 
   `git add fileName` ->`git commit`, then the merge will be finished.

   Now you can checkout to master branch and make changes, you can also merge the changes into feature branch again